# Get the count of users before 90 days records from the e_date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5.3

Database table i have:

---

```
S.no  |   j_id  |age | e_date       |
-------------------------------------
 1    |     1   |32  |  2018-05-09  |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     1   |32  |  2018-05-09  |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     2   |32  |  2018-05-09  |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |      2   |32  |  2018-04-16 |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     1   |32  |  2018-09-16  |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     3   |32  |  2018-04-16  |
------------------------------------
```

In my table I have expiry date I want to get the count of the result whose expiry date (90 days before) is equal to current date.
like I have expiry date 2018-05-09 and current date is 2018-02-2018 (90 days before date ) now i want to get to the count of the 90 days before result by query.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourtable
where datediff(CURDATE(), e_date) > 90
```

try to use datediff to get the different date count in day. Hope that this is what you want to get.

Comment: your datediff(CURDATE(), e_date) > 90 would return the dates that have more than 90 days, also if you change it back to datediff(CURDATE(), e_date) < 90  would get the date that have less than 89 days. so you either need to add +1 to 90 or to replace < with <= so will include 90.

Comment: yes, i am assuming he wants all the records that are 90 days after expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the current date, you can use [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate), [CURRENT_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date), and [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) any one of these functions would get the current date. While the [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) will get the difference between two periods (start date to end date).

If you only need to get the expiry dates that fit the 90 days condition use this :

```
SELECT e_date
FROM tableName
WHERE 
    e_date >= NOW()
AND datediff(e_date, NOW()) <= 90
```

In the query, you're scanning for future dates (from the current date and forward) and then get the differences, if the differences is less than or equal to 90 days, then it'll be selected.

if you need to show how many days left to each user:

```
SELECT sno, datediff(e_date, NOW())
FROM test 
WHERE 
    e_date >= NOW()
AND datediff(e_date, NOW()) <= 90
```

Comment: what is `=>` supposed to do? Don't you mean `>=`?

Comment: @Pevara oops, good catch, I missed this one, thanks for the notice

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep the logic on the PHP side as much as possible, so I would probably calculate my expiry date in PHP and just add a simple where to the query. In Laravel that could look something like this:

```
$expireTreshold = Carbon::now()->addDays(90);
$expireCount = $myModel->where('e_date', '<=', $expireTreshold)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will work fine.**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE e_date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY;
```

OR

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE e_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY;
```

**cheers :)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$your_date = "2018-01-01";
query = 'SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM thetable WHERE e_date =
DATE_ADD($your_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY)';
```